# How to do dynamic loop in WebGL GLSL

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

I try to do a Gaussian Filter in GLSL as following:

```
int cnt = (blurLen - 1) / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= blurLen; i++) {
    float s1 = float(i - cnt);
    vec3 off1 = vec3(v1[0]*s1, v1[1]*s1, v1[2]*s1);
    vec3 base = T + off1;
    for (int j = 0; j <= blurLen; j++) {
        float s2 = float(j - cnt);
        vec3 off2 = vec3(v1[0]*s2, v1[1]*s2, v1[2]*s2);
        cubetex += kernel3[j] * textureCube(skybox, base + off2);
    }
}
```

but got an error: ERROR: 0:49: 'i' : Loop index cannot be compared with non-constant expression

I also tried While loop, but got: ERROR: 0:51: 'while' : This type of loop is not allowed

So how should I do this?

Comment: Where does `blurLen` come from? Do you have a maximum possible upper-bound for the value? If so, try `for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) if( i <= blurLen ) break; ...` instead.

Comment: blurLen is a uniform sent in. That should be a workaround. @Dai